# XML-RPC: Getting category list from a wordpress site with xml-rpc

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

How we can get categeroy of wordpress site by xml-rpc.
i now that we need to use username and pass to connect to the site.

```
set_time_limit(0);
include("xmlrpc.inc"); 
$GLOBALS['xmlrpc_internalencoding'] = 'UTF-8';
define ('DOMAIN', 'abc.com'); // wordpress server
define ('BLOGID', 1); 
define ('USER', 'admin'); // wordpress admin account
define ('PASSWORD', 'pass'); // wordpress password
```

How i will continue to get the category list?

how i will use wp.getCategories class?
i have a code like this i do not know it is good or not

```
$categories = $wp->getCategoriesEx($blogID = 1);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my own code...

```
class WpXmlRpc {
    private $XmlRpcURL;
    private $UserName;
    private $PassWord;

    public function __construct($xmlrpcurl, $username, $password) {
        $this->XmlRpcURL = $xmlrpcurl;
        $this->UserName  = $username;
        $this->PassWord = $password;
    }

    private function send_request($requestname, $params) {
        $request = xmlrpc_encode_request($requestname, $params);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->XMLRPCURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
        $results = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $results;
    }

    public function getCategories() {
        $params = array();
        return $this->send_request('wp.getCategories', $params); // your results!
    }
}
```

Your result will be an array something like this...

```
Array(
    'Request Name' => 'wp.getCategories',
    'Result' => Array(
        'category',
        'category',
        'category'
    )
```

Comment: This one working on my localhost but doesnt work on godaddy hosting. Hosting says xmlrpc enabled but it occurs some error $request = xmlrpc_encode_request($requestname, $params);  ı do not know how we can find a solution with xmlrpc.inc of eddie.

Comment: What kind of hosting do you have? Go Daddy's shared hosting accounts are not permitted to use XML-RPC because of security concerns. If it's a dedicated host, contact Go Daddy. I've had issues in the past with some things not being enabled, even though they kept insisting they were (mod_rewrite comes to mind).